# Como habilitar a opção "Adicionar Controller" no menu?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

Recentemente a opção do meu `Adicionar controller` sumiu do menu.
Estou usando Visual Studio 2013, e o projeto é ASP NET MVC, versão 5.1.
Como fixar esse problema?

[image: Ausência do Botão]

Comment: Sumiu só nesse projeto ou de todos projetos MVC? Se você criar um novo, para testar, continua sem a opção?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um novo projeto MVC 5.1. Se a opção funcionar nesse novo projeto, abra o novo arquivo *.csproj* em um editor de texto e procure a tag `<ProjectTypeGuids>`. Ela contém a lista de GUIDs de templates associados ao projeto. Um desses GUIDs é o de projetos MVC.

Compare com o *.csproj* de seu projeto original e adicione o que estiver faltando.

Isso já aconteceu comigo em versões anteriores do MVC e eu corrigi dessa maneira.

Comment: opa, obrigado, quem tiver o mesmo problema adiciona o {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}; no <ProjectTypeGuids>, que estava faltando.

<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>

Answer (score 0):

NO visual studio 2012 essa opção já vem por default como sabe. Já tentou usar o mesmo atalho do VS12: CTRL+M, CTRL+C ?

Comment: tentei os atalhos e não reconheceu, a opçao veio por padrao no 2013 também, o problema que ela simplesmente sumiu do menu alguns dias pra ca, e nao estou identificando uma forma de habilitar ela novamente.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa resposta. É dito lá que na ultima versão foi adicionado de novo o botão. Tu já chegou a ver se a versão que tu tem é a ultima release? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623516/in-visual-studio-2013-asp-net-mvc-5-how-do-i-add-a-new-controller